# Gabriel Phthalamide Synthesis of 1-Phenylethylamine

Tags: organic-chemistry, amines

I had learnt that due to the nature of the Gabriel synthesis reaction being $S_{N}2$, the alkyl halide used must have a primary alkyl group. However, in an exam (JEE Main 2023), it was mentioned that the following compound may be prepared by Gabriel synthesis.

[image]

My question is: is it true that 1-Phenylethylamine may be prepared using Gabriel Phthalamide synthesis? If so, how is it possible? I mean, won't the nucleophile in the reaction preferentially act as a base and cause an E-2 reaction instead since the alkyl group is secondary in nature?

Comment: This works because of the reactivity of benzyl halides due to the stability of the intermediate benzylic cation. Phthalimide anion is not a good base.

Comment: @Waylander But in Sn2 no intermediate cation is formed.

Comment: You sure?  The reaction is a mixture of SN2 and SN1 because of the stability of the benzylic cation

Comment: Well that's what I'd learnt at least... I may be wrong but the sources I've read from say it's Sn2... however, if you have any resources that suggest otherwise, I'd love to know

Comment: @Waylander that's the reason as far as I know, generally Gabriel synthesis only works for primary halides.

Comment: I question whether or not the problem is made up or from the chemical literature.

Comment: @SrishDutta  I would not use Gabriel for this transformation, Sodium Azide followed by reduction is superior by a long way. However having 40+ years experience as a lab-based synthetic chemist I am confident in saying that the stability of benzylic cations is a real effect.

Comment: @Waylander I agree with the fact that Gabriel synthesis isn't the most useful here, however, the problem solution states it is which I don't understand how... as you mentioned stability of benzylic cations can contribute but if so can you explain how that aids the Sn2 process exactly

Comment: @SrishDutta  The reaction is a mixture of SN and SN2. The stability of the benzylic cation aids the SN1 reaction. Gabriel is SN2 WITH PRIMARY HALIDES, here it is SN1/2 mix.

Comment: But then why does the reaction fail in case of tertiary halides and other secondary halides

Comment: In the case of secondary halides the cation formed by E1 is less stable than benzylic cations and eliminates to alkenes faster than capture by Phthalimide anion. In the case of tertiary halides, steric hindrance prevents it. Phthalimide anion is too bulky a nucleophile to efficiently attack the cation.

Comment: Oh alright, that's good to know... @Waylander I have a few doubts regarding the mechanism, would it be okay to move it to a chat room?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149361/discussion-between-srish-dutta-and-waylander).